# How to access a SQL database using Glassfish and DataSource

Tags: java, sql, database, glassfish, datasource

I want to connect to a database that is created on WAMP. It is a SQL database that I created using SQL Buddy on WAMP.

When I run the code it showed

```
SEVERE: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
```

I found out I should use the asadmin command to disbale the JNDI naming on glassfish which worked once but again it showed the same error.

```
public Connection DbConnection(){

                        Connection con = null;
                        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
                        ds.setDatabaseName("mydatabase");
                        ds.setDescription("Authorization");
                        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                        ctx.bind("jdbc/mydatabase", ds);
                        ds.getConnection("root", "");
                        return con;
}

public void myStatement(){

                   PreparedStatement pst;
                   Connection conn = DbConnection();   
                   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                   pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select *" +
                                               " from Member WHERE Username = ? ");
                   pst.setString(1, username);
                   conn.commit();
                   pst.close();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function DbConnection() returns null because you don't return any value.  Neither do you create any Connection instance.  If you're creating the DataSource manually, you won't need to bind it to jndi.

If you're creating a DataSource, get the Connection from the DataSource object (via its getConnection() method)

Comment: in the actual code it reurns con, I have updated the question, I am using ds to access the getconnection is that wrong?

Comment: The while point of having a DataSource is to get a connection from it.  You should actually make the DataSource a singleton across all your server, but that's a different story.  However, looking at your code, con is set to null, and is never updated.  Try changing the second to last line to "con = ds.getConnection("root", "");"  That said, I would read some basic documentation about how to use a DataSource, as this will not perform in any production system.